# angularjs multiple controllers same $http request cache

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

Working on a application that requires multiple components to be displayed on the same page that need data from the same api url.

As per example I have two components, one is a breadcrumb one is the actual data container and both of them will request the status of a component in order to display relevant data.

## **data factory**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('data', function($http) { 
        this.getStatus = function() {
            return $http.get('/api/status/');
        }

        return this;
    });
```

## controller 1

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('breadcrumb', function(data, breadcrumbProcessor) {
         var _self = this;

         data
             .getStatus()
             .then(function(response) {
                 _self.activeBreadcrumb = breadcrumbProcessor(response.data); 
             });
    });
```

## controller 2

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('form', function(data, formProcessor) {
         var _self = this;

         data
             .getStatus()
             .then(function(response) {
                 _self.activeForm = formProcessor(response.data); 
             });
    });
```

The first component will be a breadcrumb that shows the stage of the process while the second component will be a page where you show a form depending on the stage. So I will call for both components the same api "GET:/api/stage/" which will case 2 requests to be made to the server.

Is it possible (and if so how would it look like) to make an interceptor or service that acts like a filter for the requests and merges them into a single request?

Comment: In my opinion, this question cannot be answer unless: (1) You explain in a clear way **why do you need two requests at all** and (2) **who** is the one that receives the requests (meaning what is running at your server side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it using the angular http cache as stated in docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

I have a http interceptor that I use to inject the auth token and there I set cache = true only for GET requests.

So now, my interceptor has something like

```
function request(config) {

    ...

    if(config.method == "GET") {
        config.cache = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

and that seems to do the trick just right.

Answer (score 0):

Blitz, why you page controller cant make the call for this two components and send the data to your components ?

I mean, you need to have a controller which use your data factory. Then you pass the data by scope to your breadcrumb component/directive as same as your form. Something like this :

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ParentController', function (data, $scope) {
    data.getStatus()
             .then(function(response) {
                 $scope.yourData = response.data; 
             });
  })
  .directive('breadcrumb',   function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      transclude: false,
      scope: {
        yourData: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'directives/breadcrumb.html',
      link: function(scope){
        scope.$watch('yourData', function (newValue) {
          scope.activeBreadcrumb = breadcrumbProcessor(newValue);
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('yourForm',   function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      transclude: false,
      scope: {
        yourData: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'directives/your-form.html',
      link: function(scope){      
        scope.$watch('yourData', function (newValue) {
          scope.activeForm = formProcessor(newValue);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  <breadcrumb your-data="yourData" />
  <your-form your-data="yourData" />  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use your factory differently to get the stored data if it's available:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('data', function($http) {
    var vm = this;

    // save to inner variables. those are not
    // accessible from outside the factory
    var statusPromise = $q.defer();

    vm.status = deferred.promise;

    // now, the data is fetched when this factory is
    // initialized (included somewhere)
    $http.get('/api/status/').then(function(res) {
      statusPromise.resolve(res.data);
    });

    return vm;
});
```

This way, you always get a promise when requesting the status.
if $http already finished, this will return a **resolved promise**.
if not, this will still return a **promise** (that will get resolved later).

This means that once this factory is initialized, the data is fetched. If you don't want that behaviour, you can create a `getStatus` function with the following syntax:

```
this.getStatus = function() {
  if (!vm.promiseResolvedAlready) {
    $http.get('/api/status/').then(function(res) {
      statusPromise.resolve(res.data);
      vm.promiseResolvedAlready = true;
    });
  }

  return vm.status;
}
```

and remove the inline `$http` request. That way, the first time someone calls `getStatus`, the status will actually update the promise. Up until that point, the promise will remain unresolved.